# How can I build every committed revision in Quickbuild?

Tags: continuous-integration, quickbuild

I find that if I schedule a periodic build with anything approaching "immediately upon checkin" (e.g. "every 15 seconds") that build requests start piling up on top of each other, because the scheduler will wait for the actual build (which takes ~5 minutes) to complete. How do I get quickbuild to build every available revision separately without clogging up the machine queues?

*Disclaimer: It's possible I'm trying to do something hopelessly unnecessary. :)*